# How does pip discover the dependencies of a package

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

I thought pip identified the dependencies of a package from the dependencies listed in `setup.py`, or from the dependencies listed in `requirements.txt`/`pyproject.toml`. But I found a package which doesn't have a `requirements.txt`, and specifies only a few dependencies in `setup.py`.

When I `pip install` this package from PYPI, or from local source code, pip finds a bunch of dependencies and builds the environment. How?

Comment: maybe it does it recursivly - when it installs some dependency then it checks if it has other dependencies.

Comment: Have you considered that `pip` knows about indirect dependencies? If A imports B and declares it, and B imports C and declares it, then A can import C without having to declare it.

Comment: Yes - I figured that probably is what happens. So does pip find all import statements within the package, `pip install` those packages and then their subsequent dependencies? Are `requirements.txt` files then only really needed if you want to explicitly control the versions installed?

Comment: @LouisF-H "*…does pip find all import statements within the package…*" No, it finds dependencies the same way — downloads the package and processes its wheel meta info or `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`.

Comment: Here's where I got confused: module in Package A imports `librosa`. But package A doesn't list librosa as a dependency in it's `setup.py`. But package A lists package B as a dependency, and package B lists librosa in its `setup.py`. Not sure if that's best practice, but I think I understand how it works now.